# Is there a way to get default currency using apex in single currency org?

Tags: apex, multi-currency, currency

I know we can use userinfo.CurrencyIsoCode to get currencycode for user in multi currency org. For single currency org we can manually look into company information and see currency locale.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_currency_set_locale.htm&type=5

But is there any way we can use apex to get currency code for single currency org's. I checked both organization and user object if there is any field for default currency but there is no field. Currencytype object is also not enabled in single currency org.

I need to know if there is any other salesforce object from where we can get this information. I don't want to create a custom object where admin can store this information.

Comment: How about https://webkul.com/blog/get-default-org-currency-apex/?

Comment: @cropedy I am not asking same question. We are building a application that is not in salesforce but need currency details from salesforce. I have already mentioned in my question that I need solution for single currency org. In the solution given in question you marked as duplicate we are using a custom object where we have to store currency type of user. I wanted to know if there is any salesforce object from where I can get this detail. Please check my question again.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal No this blog will not solve my problem. I know solution for multi currency org. I need to know something for single currency org. Thanks.

Comment: have an apex rest endpoint that can be consumed by external systems?

Comment: Yes .. it can work both way either they can query directly from salesforce or I can build a endpoint

Comment: @PranayJaiswal found solution we can use connectApi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use connectApi to get currency details. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_features.htm

We can use default​Currency​IsoCode in ConnectApi.Features to get iso code.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_usersettings.htm

We can use currencySymbol in ConnectApi.UserSettings to get currency symbol.

```
ConnectApi.OrganizationSettings  orgSettings = ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings();
system.debug(orgSettings.UserSettings.currencySymbol);
system.debug(orgSettings.features.defaultCurrencyIsoCode);
```